# ["var"+1]=someValue - Can something like this be done?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-variables

```
function giveValue(n){
    ["r"+n]=5;
}
giveValue(10);
```

You get the idea.

The point is that I have a handful of variables with similar name, varying only in a number at the end. Using a switch statement is fine with a few variables a few times, but for this particular project it is driving me crazy. I know I can do:

```
var r2="lol";
var someVar=eval("r"+2);
//someVar=="lol"
```

And I was wondering if I can do something like this but with the dynamic reference to the left of an assignment.

Is it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with an array? Is it really that much harder to type `r[2]` instead of `r2`?

Comment: Let's just say it's too late for that.

Comment: This is not what eval() intended for.

Comment: Possible? Yes. A good idea? No. It wasn't a good idea the first guy using the first dynamic language thought of something like this, and it's didn't improve since. Use goddamn arrays if you want to store a number of values under one name and associate them to numbers (indices), or use a mapping (in JS, any object works) to associate them by strings.

Comment: It's too late for that, but not too late to mess the rest of your code up by throwing `eval` all over the place? In the long run you'll save much more time/money by fixing it now

Comment: What @Gath said. Except that I fear code like this is so fundamentally flawed that "fixing it" amounts to "incrementally rewriting the whole P.O.S.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *REALLY* want to do that, this should work:

```
function giveValue(n){
    window['r'+n] = 5;
}
giveValue(10);

console.log(r10)
```

But please, **DON'T DO IT!**

You really should [use arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328746/var1somevalue-can-something-like-this-be-done/4328759#4328759)!

Comment: I figured something like this could be done. Thank you. After seeing all the alarm answers, I'll just change the code and use arrays, but it's good to know this can happen.

Comment: @Eric: Too late, you've unleashed the monster! One more awful script out in the wild!

Comment: @navand: See that grey tick-mark next to the answers? Click the one next to the best answer to your question, to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I know that dude. But it didn't let me accept it until some minutes had passed.

Comment: @navand: Sorry, I wasn't sure what to infer from _"accept one of the two answers? what?"_

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create an array called `r`:

```
var r = [];
r[2] = 5;
```

Comment: My question is more about curiosity than practicality now. Can it be done without arrays?

Comment: @navad: Arrays are not only practical, they are also **sane** ;)

Comment: ok fine, I'll use the damn arays. I just wanted to know how it could be done